# Running server-program from a .jar file

Tags: java, cmd

I have created and am working on a server-application that monitors for specific folders and takes appropriate actions whenever files are being added.

Now I come to the point where I want to be able to shutdown the program, for example for applying a patch.

The server runs simply in a command prompt, how can I signal that I want to perform maintenance on it? I do not think reading `System.in` is feasible as I am also outputting text in the prompt.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reading System.in as System.in and System.out are different file descriptors. What this means is that by writing things in console you are not writing in the same place than when you are typing, so console output should not matter for reading commands in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

A second application can be used to communicate with the server application. You can use [Java Management Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/) or implement your own client/server communication using sockets.

Another way to achieve this is that server periodically checks for existence of an specific file somewhere on hard disk. If server finds that specific file, it will shut down.